Azure put block list returns 400 in sw
I'm trying to use blob storage, firstly i used azure put block rest api service to write data, and then i am trying to use put block list api service but i am getting status code 400 every time.
let baseURL = NSURL(string: Constants.AZURE_URL + containerType.rawValue + Constants.FOLDER_DIVIDER + fileName + token + "&comp=blocklist")! as URL

    var putBlockListRequest = URLRequest(url: baseURL)
    putBlockListRequest.httpMethod = "PUT"
    putBlockListRequest.setValue("2015-05-04", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-ms-version")
    let blockListXML = generateBlockListXML(blockIDs: [blockId])
    putBlockRequest.setValue(String(blockListXML.data(using: .utf8)!.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    putBlockRequest.httpBody = blockListXML.data(using: .utf8)

    let putBlocListTask = session.dataTask(with: putBlockListRequest) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        result = self.cloudConnectionHandler(error)
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    putBlocListTask.resume()


What are the block ids?

Generates from this code block
func generateBlockID() -> String {
let blockID = UUID().uuidString
let data = blockID.data(using: .utf8)!
let base64Encoded = data.base64EncodedString()
return base64Encoded
}


I used the Azure Put Block REST API service to write data, and then I tried to use the Put Block List API service, but I kept getting status code 400 every time.

You can refer this MS-Document regarding your error. If the block cannot be located in the list of committed or uncommitted blocks, it won't be included in the blob, and Blob Storage will respond with status code 400.
In my environment, I tried using JavaScript code to perform both requests, such as Put block and Put block list. to upload the file to Azure Blob storage.
Code:
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
const _ = require('lodash')

const account = 'venkat123'
const containerName = 'test'
const blobName = 'venkat235.wav'

let i = 0
const blockIdArray = []
const sastoken = 'your-sas token'
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('sample.wav', { highWaterMark: 1024 * 1024 })

readStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
  i++
  const blobContent = chunk
  const contentLength = chunk.length
  const blockId = Buffer.from('block' + i).toString('base64')
  console.log(blockId)
  blockIdArray.push(blockId)
  const optionsPutBlock = {
    url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}?comp=block&blockid=${blockId}&${sastoken}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': contentLength
    },
    body: blobContent
  }
  request.put(optionsPutBlock, callbackPutBlock)
})

readStream.on('end', () => {
  const xmlBlockList = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList>' + (_.map(blockIdArray, (id) => { return `<Latest>${id}</Latest>` })).join('') + '</BlockList>'
  console.log(xmlBlockList)
  const xmlBlockListLength = new TextEncoder().encode(xmlBlockList).length
  const optionsPutBlockList = {
    url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}?comp=blocklist&${sastoken}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': xmlBlockListLength,
    },
    body: xmlBlockList
  }
  console.log(optionsPutBlockList.body)
  request.put(optionsPutBlockList, callbackPutBlockList)
})

function callbackPutBlock (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode, response.statusMessage,"Block created")
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

function callbackPutBlockList (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode, response.statusMessage)
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

Output:
Ym***sx
Ym**2sy
Ym***2sz
Ym***s0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList><Latest>Ym***sx</Latest><Latest>Ymx**sy</Latest><Latest>Ymx***sz</Latest><Latest>Ym**s0</Latest></BlockList>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList><Latest>Ym**2sx</Latest><Latest>Ymx**sy</Latest><Latest>Ymx**sz</Latest><Latest>Ymx**s0</Latest></BlockList>
201 Created
201 Created Block created
201 Created Block created
201 Created Block created
201 Created Block created


Portal:

Reference:
Azure Block Blob: "The specified block list is invalid" when trying to create blocks and committing them - Stack Overflow by Mayank Patel.
